# NGINX X-Accel counted bandwidth

Tags: nginx, count, bandwidth

Is there please any way to monitor amount of sent data to client sent via **X-Accel** on **NGINX**? I need to subtract sent data from customer's credit *e.g. every 10 MB*.

The best way for me would be if **NGINX** can call some **Internal/URL** **PHP script** with given parameters *(e.g. user id and amount of sent data)*.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you thought about piping the access logs through a script? Retaining the logs for a period would also give you an audit trail should the costs be questioned.

Comment: I should add that `$bytes_sent` is the config option in nginx to add this to the `log_format` option.